# Update a column with multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server

UPDATE query a column with multiple values

Table Names:

```
        Book                          Author
Book_Name| Authors        Author_Name | Author_Id
---------|---------        -----------|----------
C#       | A,B            A           | 1
C++      | C              B           | 2
Java     | B,D            C           | 3
                          D           | 4
```

Update Book Table to

```
   Book
Book_Name| Authors
---------|---------
C#       | 1,2
C++      | 3
Java     | 2,4
```

Comment: You should normalize your schema. It's a bad idea to have comma-separated values in a single column.

Comment: I didn't create the database in that way it's already created so I should make changes.

Comment: @A.Konda . . . It is less effort to fix the data structure than to make this work.

Comment: It is recommended that you share your attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short as I am sure you have read. This is a bad design for a database, but this code will get you were you need to be. I created some temp tables. Note*you could make performance improvements if there is a lot of data, but based on the design I think if there is a lot of data you should redesign.

```
Declare  @Book table(Book_name Varchar(100)
                    ,Authors Varchar(100)
                    )

Declare  @Author table(Author_name Varchar(100)
                    ,Author_ID Varchar(100)
                    )

Insert into @Book
values ('C#','A,B')
,('C++','C')
,('Java','B,D')

Insert into @Author
Values ('A','1')
,('B','2')
,('C','3')
,('D','4')

Declare @CT Int = (SELECT MAX(LEN(Authors)) from @Book)
        ,@Pos int = 0

While @Pos <= @CT
BEGIN
UPDATE @Book
SET Authors = REPLACE(Authors,Author_name,Author_id)
from @Book b
inner join @Author a
on SUBSTRING(b.Authors,@POS,1) = a.Author_Name
SET @Pos = @Pos + 1
END

select * From @Book
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of data are not expected in any real scenario.

Here is one way to handle it.

```
Declare @ExecuteNo INT
Select @ExecuteNo = MAX(len(Authors) - len(replace(Authors, ',', ''))) + 1 from Book

WHILE @ExecuteNo > 0
BEGIN
    Update b
    Set b.Authors = Replace(Authors, a.Author_Name, a.Author_Id) from Book b
    cross join Author a
    where CHARINDEX(a.author_name, b.Authors) >= 1
SET @ExecuteNo = @ExecuteNo - 1
END
```